# How to config and run VictoriaMetrics with Prometheus and Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, victoriametrics

currently I'm working on a project of getting custom data, pushing it to Prometheus and visualizing it with Grafana.
I've figured out that Prometheus doesn't store data, so I decided to use VictoriaMetrics.
I downloaded vmutils and ran vmagent in cmd:

```
vmagent-windows-amd64-prod.exe 
-promscrape.config=C:\Users\UserName\prometheus\prometheus.yml 
-promscrape.config.strictParse=false 
-remoteWrite.url=https://localhost:8429/api/v1/write
```

And in prometheus.yml I wrote this:

```
remote_write:
  - url: http://localhost:8429/api/v1/write
```

After running all this vmagent started pushing error messages like this with different bytes

```
warn VictoriaMetrics/app/vmagent/remotewrite.client.go:277 
couldn't send a block with size 5508 bytes to "1:secret-url": 
Post "http://localhost:8429/api/v1/write": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client; 
re-sending the block in 60.000 seconds
```

Also Garafana couldn't get data from 8429 port.

Did I forget to config some files? Or am I running vmagent wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Prometheus *does* store data: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've figured out that Prometheus doesn't store data

Prometheus does store data and does it very well) The only limitation of Prometheus is that it can't be scaled "horizontally". To overcome this limitation many projects exist: VictoriaMetrics, Thanos, Cortex.
VictoriaMetrics can also be used instead of Prometheus - see more details here https://docs.victoriametrics.com/FAQ.html#can-i-use-victoriametrics-instead-of-prometheus

> Did I forget to config some files? Or am I running vmagent wrong? Thanks.

Actually, yes - you're using it wrong. Vmagent is a stateless service for scraping and forwarding metrics. It does not store metrics. See more about this here https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#motivation

There are two ways you can solve this:

1. Start using Prometheus without any additional hassle. It can scrape, store and visualise metrics.
2. Start using VictoriaMetrics. It can be used in a [single binary mode](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Single-server-VictoriaMetrics.html) (just as Prometheus) and in [cluster mode](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Cluster-VictoriaMetrics.html). People choose VictoriaMetrics when they want to get better compression, resource efficiency and ability to scale in future. Unfortunately, VictoriaMetrics (storage) [does not support Windows yet](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/70).

Update: VictoriaMetrics gain Windows support starting from [v1.90](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/CHANGELOG.html#v1900).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But how long can Prometheus store data? I need like 3years+.

Comment: There is no limit for Prometheus retention flag - you can set multiple years if you want. I don't know if there is any degradation with the amount of data stored, it is likely there is no impact. Unless you regularly query all the 3y of data of course)
Anyway, please take a look at https://www.robustperception.io/configuring-prometheus-storage-retention